# issuing a bash command in multiple directories from a unix shell

Tags: unix

I need to execute a short script that just renames a few files (mv).

The script is in about 50 folders, each folder is named  and currently I'm executing them from the shell and moving to the next folder using:

```
bash rename && cd ../folder01
```

Then pressing up and changing the last digit(s).

Is there a way to execute the script in all folders in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, use a for loop:

```
for f in folder*; do (cd "$f" && bash rename) ; done
```

Comment: you also don't neet to copy your script in each and every folder

Comment: @arashkordi I was copying it using  'echo folder{10..49} | xargs -n 1 cp script'